# Capturing 802.11 packet headers on Android device?

Tags: android, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I want to capture WiFi packet headers on Android using tcpdump kind of an application.  I am using an HTC dream phone (Android 1.6, Wi-Fi (802.11b/g) using a Texas Instruments WL1251B chipset). The default TI driver filters the 802.11 packet headers while doing a packet capture on the device using tcpdump. Does anybody know of a way to capture the 802.11 headers using the default TI driver?

Also, I was looking at http://bobcopeland.com/android_wifi.html, which contains instructions to install a mac80211 based driver on an android device. As mentioned in this page, I followed the instructions to create the kernel modules and loaded them up on the phone. But, I could not activate the WiFi interface after doing so (though I saw the "wlan0" interface indicating that the mac80211 driver was loaded).

So, I am stuck at this point. Can anybody advise me regarding capturing 802.11 packet headers on an android phone using either TI/mac80211 based drivers?